# C exits when writing and reading from sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to write a really basic http server in C, but some of the C behaviour I'm seeing is confusing me. As far as I can tell, this code should loop forever (and it does when the client is netcat) but when the client is a browser, it just exits (after rendering "hello world").

If it exited with an error, everything would make sense. But it seems to just happily quit with no error message! You can't just run away from an infinite while loop like that!

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>  //strlen
    #include<sys/socket.h>
    #include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
    #include<unistd.h>  //write
    #include<stdlib.h>
    
    int main(int argc , char *argv[])
    {
        int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
        struct sockaddr_in server , client;
        char *message;
        char *buffer = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: 12\n\nHello world!";
        //Create socket
        socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
        if (socket_desc == -1)
        {
            printf("Could not create socket");
        }
        
        //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
        
        //Bind
        if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            puts("bind failed");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("bind done");
        
        //Listen
        listen(socket_desc , 3);
        
        //Accept and incoming connection
        puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
        c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        int read_size;
        char client_message[2000];
        new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
        while( 1 )
        {
            write(new_socket , buffer , strlen(buffer));
            while (1){ 
                read_size = recv(new_socket , client_message , 2000 , 0);
                //send the exact same message again
                write(new_socket , buffer , strlen(buffer));
            }
        }
        
        if (new_socket<0)
        {
            perror("accept failed");
            return 1;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with firefox on linux

Comment: I figured this out: when a process listening to this server quits, it sends some sort of SIGKILL to the server. Adding #include <signal.h> to the top and signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); into main fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&c);
while (1)
{
    write(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    while (1)
    {
        read_size = recv(new_socket, client_message, 2000, 0);
        //send the exact same message again
        write(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    }
}
```

You call `accept` only once in your program - i.e. you will only ever receive one incoming request. And you infinitely send the same buffer back to the new connection - which isn't how web communications works.

What you probably want to do is to call `accept` in a loop and serve your buffer to each connection.

For instance:

```
while (1)
{
    new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&c);
    write(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    close(new_socket);
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you! So web browsers initiate a new connection every time they need information? I was testing this with telnet, and after that one accept, I was able to send multiple messages.

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie Yep - every time you browse to a new address in a browser, a new connection is made. You were able to send multiple messages in telnet in a single connection because you have an infinite loop of `read`/`write` calls - but you wouldn't have been able to connect to your server twice with two different telnet sessions.

Comment: If you want to learn more - Beej's Guide to Network Programming is a classic (and was my gateway drug to network programming :)) - [this link](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#a-simple-stream-server) teaches how to code a server, but the entire guide is worth reading.